# Integer Encryption

Tags: encryption, hash, private-key

I am looking for an encryption function (so, 1:1 mapping) that maps integer to integer.

For example, let's say I have `N1` (integer) and a `password`. I use the encryption function to get integer `N2`. Then if (and only if) I know the password I should be able to get back `N1` from `N2`.

What is the best function for that?

Comment: There is most likely a plethora of such functions and it is hard to say which one is the "best" in your case. One would need way more details to judge that.

Comment: Your question implies that you are looking for a symmatric encryption algorithm with only a key, not a key pair of a public and a private key. Although the key in a symmetric encryption is kept secret and in that sense it somewhat similar to "private", it is a difference: The private key of a key pair does not even get shared between two parties. It is private to a single party, hence a private key. Therefor, the key in a symmatric encryption, which is shared among at least two parties, is not called a private key.

Comment: Hash also implies something else: A hash, in cryptography, is usually made in a way so it is impossible to reverse it, or only with tremendous effort. The term is not used for encrypted data, which can be decrypted easily if the right key is known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [format preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) I think it is what you are looking for. For example you can use Feistel network and AES to encrypt integer and get encrypted integer. There are many examples of encrypting credit card number preserving its format.

Comment: The answer is good, but as far as i can judge, the encryption of a credit card number this way, is a bad idea. Just to spare some bytes, you forgo an IV vector, which is a _must_ in my opinion.

Comment: This is format preserving encryption so you get _encrypted_ credit card but in same format. Sometimes you cannot do better when you cannot store additional information.

Comment: I placed a comment on the wiki page, the problem is, that credit card numbers are so short, that you can easily build a rainbow-table to crack all at once (a given number always returns the same encrypted number). Even block cyphers with an IV vector would be prone to brute-forcing. So it's best not to store the number at all, or then at least do it with an IV vector.